# How to change the color of header?

Tags: beamer, formatting, themes

I downloaded a Radboud University Beamer (version 1) and try to change the color of left part of header from black to blue. i.e., How to change the black to another color as shown in the following picture?

For the `.sty` file, please see http://www.cs.ru.nl/P.Vullers/beamer.php

Thanks very much..

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,hyperref,ru,url}

% Optional: The sublogo of the presentation:
%  - the sublogo which is visible at the bottom right of each slide;
\logo{\includegraphics[width=0.6in]{CIS}}

% The title of the presentation:
%  - first a short version which is visible at the bottom of each slide;
%  - second the full title shown on the title slide;
\title[IMGS.633.01 - Optics for Imaging]{
  MATLAB Fundamentals in Optics}

% Optional: a subtitle to be dispalyed on the title slide
\subtitle{IMGS.633.01 - Optics for Imaging}

% The author(s) of the presentation:
%  - again first a short version to be displayed at the bottom;
%  - next the full list of authors, which may include contact information;
\author[ ]{
    \\\medskip
  {\small \url{ }} \\ 
  {\small \url{ }}}

% The institute:
%  - to start the name of the university as displayed on the top of each slide
%    this can be adjusted such that you can also create a Dutch version
%  - next the institute information as displayed on the title slide
\institute[Rochester Institute of Technology]{
  Chester F. Carlson Center for Imaging Science \\
   Rochester Institute of Technology }

% Add a date and possibly the name of the event to the slides
%  - again first a short version to be shown at the bottom of each slide
%  - second the full date and event name for the title slide
\date[1st January 2015]{
  1st January 2015 \\
  Happy New Year :-)}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \titlepage
\end{frame}

 \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}

  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

....

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! How can we help if we can't see the code you're using? Please edit your post to include a complete but minimal piece of code we can use for testing.

Comment: At least a download link... See also [the wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors) for general informations about colors

Comment: Sorry, I added a link of this style and included my code... Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The black color comes from the `section in head/foot` color, so one posiibility is to set this color according to your needs using something like

```
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=blue!40!black,fg=white}
```

in the preamble of your document. This, however, will affect some other elements of the frames, such as the left half of the footline and the rightmost part of the frametitle which also use the `section in head/foot` color specification.

If you want to change the color only for the left part of the headline, you'll need to set a beamer color, for example

```
\setbeamercolor{mysection in head/foot}{bg=blue!40!black,fg=white}
```

and a redefinition of the headline template, as the following example shows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,hyperref,ru,url}

\setbeamercolor{mysection in head/foot}{bg=blue!40!black,fg=white}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{myru theme}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \pgfdeclareimage[height=.9\@tempdimb]{logo}{ru_logo}%
  \logo{\pgfuseimage{logo}}%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.125ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{mysection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb,right]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\vfil\textbf{\footnotesize\insertshortinstitute~~}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertlogo\vfil\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\title[RU style for Beamer]{
  Radboud University style for Beamer \LaTeX}
\subtitle{Show where you're from}
\author[Pim Vullers MSc]{
  Pim Vullers MSc \\\medskip
  {\small \url{p.vullers@cs.ru.nl}} \\ 
  {\small \url{http://www.cs.ru.nl/~pim/}}}
\institute[Radboud University Nijmegen]{
  Institute for Computing and Information Sciences -- Digital Security \\
  Radboud University Nijmegen}
\date[slides Example 2010]{
  the 1st example presentation 2010 \\
  7th October 2010}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Introduction}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item This is just a short example
    \item The comments in the \LaTeX\ file are most important
    \item This is just the result after running pdflatex
    \item The style is based on the webpage \url{http://www.ru.nl/}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Background information}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Background information}

  \begin{block}{Slides with \LaTeX}
    Beamer offers a lot of functions to create nice slides using \LaTeX.
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{The basis}
    This style uses the following default styles:
    \begin{itemize}
      \item split
      \item whale
      \item rounded
      \item orchid
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

One of the frames of the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much!!! That is exactly what I want. BTW, could you explain what is that mean `blue!40!black` in preamble `\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=blue!40!black,fg=white}`  What if I want to change the head to another specific color knowing RGB value? @Gonzalo Medina

Comment: @ChiZhang You're welcome. `blue!40!black` means a shade of 40% blue and 60% black (it's the syntax used by the `color` or `xcolor` packages). In the case of a RGB color, define the color first using, for example, `\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{123,34,56}` and then you can use it: `\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=mycolor,fg=white}`.

Comment: @ChiZhang By the way, don't forget that you can accept the answer, if you consider it solved your problem, by clicking the checkmark to its left; in case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).